# Change MySql view in to a select statement

Tags: mysql

I've a view called wallcitiescouncils, and a Procedure that returns values from this View.
I need faster respose so I want to change this View in to a Select statement, but without success for the moment.

I need results form two tables, cities and councils, this is my View code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW wallcitiescouncils AS
SELECT
    concat('p',cities.id) as id,
    cities.name as name,
    cities.country_id,
    concat(cities.name,' (',councils.name,'), ',states.name,', ',countries.name) as fullname,
    'City' as type

FROM cities
    JOIN countries  ON (cities.country_id = countries.id)
    JOIN states     ON (cities.state_id = states.id)
    JOIN councils   ON (cities.council_id = councils.id)

UNION ALL

SELECT
    concat('c',councils.id) as id,
    councils.name as name,
    councils.country_id,
    concat(councils.name,'(Council)') as fullname,
    'Council' as type

FROM councils
```

And this one my Procedure:

```
BEGIN
  SELECT name as city, id as city_id, fullname
  FROM wallcitiescouncils
  WHERE country_id = _country_id AND name LIKE CONCAT(search , '%') ORDER BY name LIMIT _limit;
END
```

I need to change `FROM wallcitiescouncils` with a Select statement so I do not to have to call the View.

This is one of my attempts, but results aren't correct (I haven't councils results and in 'fullname' always get the same council name), I use councils_id (only present in cities table) to try to know if is a city or a city coucil:

```
SELECT
    if(
        cities.council_id is null,
        concat('c',councils.id),
        concat('p',cities.id)
        ) as id,
    if(
        cities.council_id is null,
        councils.name,
        cities.name
        ) as name,

    if(
        cities.council_id is null,
        councils.country_id,
        cities.country_id
        ) as country_id,
    if(
        cities.council_id is null,
        concat(councils.name,' (Municipio)'),
        concat(cities.name,' (',councils.name,'), ',states.name,', ',countries.name)
        )  as fullname
FROM councils, cities
    JOIN countries  ON (country_id = countries.id)
    JOIN states     ON (state_id = states.id)
    /*JOIN councils   ON (cities.council_id = councils.id)*/
where cities.id = 1 or councils.id = 1 limit 200
```

Comment: Why do you think that changing the view into a select statement will make anything work faster? You have a `LIKE` in your query, you didn't post output of `EXPLAIN` so how did you conclude where bottleneck is?

Comment: [MySQL VIEW as performance troublemaker](https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/08/12/mysql-view-as-performance-troublemaker/)

Comment: @Devart you're linking a 10 year old article. There's a standard way of determining bottlenecks in MySQL, it's repeated in every single question. Let's do that and get correct information instead of guesstimating.

Comment: Yes, I see. It would be interesting to check on new version. It depends on server optimizer.

Comment: Mjh you must forgive me, I do not have too much knowledge of MySql. I ran the EXPLAIN with the view and @Devart solution and the results are identical, but with the Devart solution the queries are a few hundredths of a second faster. I guess if there are more rows I will notice the difference more. Even so the query takes about a second in both cases. I will try to create a table with several indexes to improve it. Anyway Devart's answer is correct based on my question, whether it is faster or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query firstly-

```
SELECT name as city, id as city_id, fullname FROM (
  SELECT
    concat('p',cities.id) as id,
    cities.name as name,
    cities.country_id,
    concat(cities.name,' (',councils.name,'), ',states.name,', ',countries.name) as fullname,
    'City' as type

  FROM cities
    JOIN countries  ON (cities.country_id = countries.id)
    JOIN states     ON (cities.state_id = states.id)
    JOIN councils   ON (cities.council_id = councils.id)

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    concat('c',councils.id) as id,
    councils.name as name,
    councils.country_id,
    concat(councils.name,'(Council)') as fullname,
    'Council' as type
  FROM councils
  ) v
WHERE
  v.country_id = _country_id AND v.name LIKE CONCAT(search , '%') ORDER BY v.name LIMIT _limit;
```